# Weblogic dont detect https from load balancer

Tags: java, weblogic

My weblogic is in load balancer this load balancer is configurate with ssl certificate, but weblogic dont.
When i run wsdl service of weblogic the schemalocation write with http and client generate  with error because wsdl have http and the real location is https

Any idea that configurate in weblogic??

Comment: WebLogic must be informed that you have a SSL end point in front of it. You have to activate (check) the "WebLogic Plugin Enabled" option if the domain configuration under the Configuration/Web Applications tab in the admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you need to enable the "WebLogic Plugin Enabled" option at either domain or cluster level. If you use Apache or OHS with mod_wl, you are done. However, if you use any other load balancer, you need to configure it to add a "WL-Proxy-SSL" header with a value of "true" to the request. There's a good blog on this subject: http://www.ateam-oracle.com/ssl-offloading-and-weblogic-server/.

If you still have an incorrect hostname / port in the WSDL binding block, try configuring the front-end host entry at cluster or server level.

Comment: Thanks works with weblogic. Configuration and header